# cmake error: QGLWidget: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I am trying to use cmake with Qt, but I get the following error when I build.

```
QGLWidget: No such file or directory
```

In my CMakeLists.txt file I have:

```
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
qt5_use_modules(SHWidget Widgets)
```

Comment: Same problem here, sadly it works with .pro, can't convert it to accept in the cmake, have you resolved your issue somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the `QtOpenGL` module [docs](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtopengl/qtopengl-index.html):

> Warning: Apart from the QGLWidget class, this module should not be
>   used anymore for new code.

In other words you need to add the `QtOpenGL` add-on module to your build.

Comment: How can I add the QtOpenGL add-on module to my build? I have tried the following: cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

set(QT_USE_QTOPENGL TRUE)

find_package(Qt5Widgets)

find_package(Qt5OpenGL)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

qt5_use_modules(myprogram Widgets)

Comment: @user2670468 Doesn't it need to be `qt5_use_modules(myprogram Widgets OpenGL)`?

Comment: @user2670468 Then you are doing other things wrong as well, as that is correct: http://www.kdab.com/using-cmake-with-qt-5/

Comment: It seems to me that QGLWidget is outdated. I am rather trying to implement QOpenGLConetext with a QWindow. Do you think that this is a good approach?

Comment: @user2670468 I last used `QGLWidget` back in v4.8 when is was the usual way of handling things.  For v5+ I use QML (e.g. https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquick/scenegraph-openglunderqml.html) - I don't even think about `QWidget`-based stuff any more.  I used to be very cynical about QML, but after trying it I'm now a *complete* convert!