# Display glut window on Qt widget / QWindow

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am trying to configure one of the samples bundled in the OptiX 3.0.1 SDK to display in a Qt Widget.

The sample currently renders to a glut window and makes use of glViewport. Is there a way that I can change the glut window to a Qt Widget or make the glut window display on a Qt widget?

The sample makes use of a vertex buffer object:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, vboId);
```

I have created a class that inherits from QWindow. Is it possible to use the vertex buffer object to render to the QWindow?

Comment: there is entity called QGlWidget in Qt - isnt that suited for your needs?

Comment: I was thinking about using QGLWidget. Can you advise me on how to render to QGLWidget from a vbo?

Comment: QGLwidget specifies initialize and paintgl methods, I dont know exact mechanics but it should work if you just create QGLWidget and do VBO calls within qglwidget' initialize or paintgl methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GLUT is just another (very spartanic) application framework. You can replace it completely with Qt and QGLWidget.

- glutCreateWindow → creation of a QGLWidget instance
- glutDisplayFunc & a display handler → reimplement QGLWidget::paintGL in a derived class
- glutReshapeFunc & a resize handler → reimplement QGLWidget::resizeGL in a derived class
- user input functions → reimplement the event methods of QWidget

Comment: I am using a QWindow and setting the surface format to QWindow::OpenGLSurface. Is this a good approach?

Comment: @user2670468: No, because that simply tells Qt to use OpenGL for rendering its stuff. It doesn't give things like access to context management though; you need an active OpenGL context when performing OpenGL calls. What you did doesn't assert you have one in the paint function. Use a QGLWidget. That's what it's meant for.

Comment: Thank you. I am struggling to set up my cmake file with QGLWidget and therefor I tried to use a QWindow. Can you please see my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20266235/cmake-error-qglwidget-no-such-file-or-directory) about the cmake file.

Comment: @user2670468: Seems my knowledge on Qt and OpenGL is a bit outdated as it's based on Qt-4. I have to get around with Qt-5 yet.

Comment: According to this [article](http://www.kdab.com/opengl-in-qt-5-1-part-1/) QGLWidget is outdated in Qt5 and that is why I tried a QWindow.