# Linking and UIC order in a CMake Qt project

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

Talking about a Qt 5.3.2 project which is buildt using cmake.
This is a calling order problem between UIC execution and target_link_libraries... unfortunately *not* in that order.

Below this text you will find

1.) a (still functional) excerpt section of my CMakeLists.txt and

2.) an excerpt of the the output of the command 'cmake .'

3.) the output of a following call to 'make' without using the
generated headers like 'ui_main.h'.

If (in the source of my library *libqt.a*) I require 'ui_main.h' the
make process crashes not finding the header. Looking at the
non-crashing make output shows why:

```
[..]
Scanning dependencies of target qt
[ 29%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/qt.dir/home/kochmn/projects/sentinel/src/qt/form_main.cpp.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/qt.dir/qt_automoc.cpp.o
Linking CXX static library libqt.a
[..]
[ 52%] Generating ui_main.h
[..]
```

Make would generate *libqt.a* *before* generating the required header file.
So I experimented using code like

```
target_link_libraries(sentinel
  ${Qt5Widgets_LIBRARIES} ${Qt5Gui_LIBRARIES} ${Qt5Core_LIBRARIES})

add_library(optimization "${DIR_SRC}/optimization/linalg.cpp")
add_library(qt "${DIR_SRC}/qt/form_main.cpp")

target_link_libraries(sentinel qt optimization)
```

to no avail. The question: How can I motivate cmake to *first* run UIC generating the ui-header files and *then* compiling my *libqt.a*?

### Appendix

```
# 2.8.11 instead of 2.8 required for automatic linking to the qtmain.lib
# library if this ever should expand to Windows.
# (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

project(sentinel)

set( CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON )
# CMake uses uic in order to generate header files from .ui forms from designer.
set ( CMAKE AUTOUIC ON )
# Auto-generating functions write their headers into the build directory.
# Hence the build directory should be included.
set( CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON )

#> Getting the Qt essentials. ----------------------------------------
# Widgets finds its own dependencies (QtGui and QtCore).
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)

message ("Found Qt5Widgets Version ${Qt5Widgets_VERSION_STRING}")

# All those darling variables are explained here:
# http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html
message("Core    FOUND: ${Qt5Core_FOUND}")
message("Gui     FOUND: ${Qt5Gui_FOUND}")
message("Widgets FOUND: ${Qt5Widgets_FOUND}")
message("Core    VERSION: ${Qt5Core_VERSION_STRING}")
message("Gui     VERSION: ${Qt5Gui_VERSION_STRING}")
message("Widgets VERSION: ${Qt5Widgets_VERSION_STRING}")
message("Core    INCLUDE: ${Qt5Core_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message("Gui     INCLUDE: ${Qt5Gui_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message("Widgets INCLUDE: ${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message("Core    LIBRARIES: ${Qt5Core_LIBRARIES}")
message("Gui     LIBRARIES: ${Qt5Gui_LIBRARIES}")
message("Widgets LIBRARIES: ${Qt5Widgets_LIBRARIES}")
message("Core    DEFINITIONS: ${Qt5Core_DEFINITIONS}")
message("Gui     DEFINITIONS: ${Qt5Gui_DEFINITIONS}")
message("Widgets DEFINITIONS: ${Qt5Widgets_DEFINITIONS}")
message("Core    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS: ${Qt5Core_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS}")
message("Gui     COMPILE_DEFINITIONS: ${Qt5Gui_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS}")
message("Widgets COMPILE_DEFINITIONS: ${Qt5Widgets_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS}")
message("Core    EXECUTABLE_COMPILE_FLAGS: ${Qt5Core_EXECUTABLE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
message("Gui     EXECUTABLE_COMPILE_FLAGS: ${Qt5Gui_EXECUTABLE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
message("Widgets EXECUTABLE_COMPILE_FLAGS: ${Qt5Widgets_EXECUTABLE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")

include_directories(
  ${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Qt5Core_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Qt5Gui_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_definitions(${Qt5Widgets_DEFINITIONS})
#add_definitions(${Qt5Core_DEFINITIONS}) # Unnecessary. In Widgets.
#add_definitions(${Qt5Gui_DEFINITIONS})  # Unnecessary. In Widgets.
#< -------------------------------------------------------------------

set (DEBUG 1)
set (SENTINEL_NAME "Sentinel GL")
set (SENTINEL_VERSION_MAJOR "0")
set (SENTINEL_VERSION_MINOR "1")
set (SENTINEL_VERSION "${SENTINEL_VERSION_MAJOR}.${SENTINEL_VERSION_MINOR}")

## Compiler flags
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${Qt5Widgets_EXECUTABLE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
#  ${Qt5Core_EXECUTABLE_COMPILE_FLAGS} ${Qt5Gui_EXECUTABLE_COMPILE_FLAGS} #<-- redundant.

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
  message("Using GnuCXX compiler.")
  add_definitions("-O0 -std=c++0x -lSOIL -llapacke -lblas")
endif()

if (DEBUG MATCHES 1)
  message("\nBuilding DEBUG build.")
  add_definitions(-Wall)
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
endif()

set(DIR_BASE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/..")
set(DIR_SRC "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../src")
set(DIR_RES "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../resources")
set(DIR_BUILD "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../build")

# Generated using uic FormMain.ui > ui_FormMain.h
set(qt_H
  "${DIR_BUILD}/ui_main.h" "${DIR_BUILD}/ui_dialog_setup_game.h")
# Generated using the trusty QtDesigner.
set(qt_UI
  "${DIR_SRC}/ui/main.ui" "${DIR_SRC}/ui/dialog_setup_game.ui")
# My own hand-written XML describing the internal resources.
set(qt_QRC "${DIR_RES}/application.qrc")

# generate rules for building source files that moc generates
QT5_WRAP_CPP(qt_H_MOC ${qt_H})
# generate rules for building header files from the ui files
QT5_WRAP_UI(qt_UI_H ${qt_UI})
# Resource Handling. QRC: "Qt Resource Collection"
QT5_ADD_RESOURCES(qt_RCCS ${qt_QRC})
# btw.: rcc generates a C program from ./resources/application.qrc
# However, this is not needed. cmake sees to that. :-)
#< -------------------------------------------------------------------

include_directories("${DIR_SRC}/include" "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")

add_executable(sentinel "${DIR_SRC}/sentinel.cpp" ${qt_H_MOC} ${qt_UI_H} ${qt_RCCS})

# Available modules are listed here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmodules.html
#   find /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake -iname "*.cmake*" | less
# Note: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20266235/cmake-error-qglwidget-no-such-file-or-directory
qt5_use_modules(sentinel Widgets Gui Core)

add_library(optimization "${DIR_SRC}/optimization/linalg.cpp")
add_library(qt "${DIR_SRC}/qt/form_main.cpp")

target_link_libraries(sentinel
  ${Qt5Widgets_LIBRARIES} ${Qt5Gui_LIBRARIES} ${Qt5Core_LIBRARIES}
  qt optimization
)

kochmn@Ulyss:~/projects/sentinel/build$ cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Found Qt5Widgets Version 5.3.2
Core    FOUND: 1
Gui     FOUND: 1
Widgets FOUND: 1
Core    VERSION: 5.3.2
Gui     VERSION: 5.3.2
Widgets VERSION: 5.3.2
Core    INCLUDE: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/;/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5//mkspecs/linux-g++-64
Gui     INCLUDE: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/;/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui;/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5//mkspecs/linux-g++-64
Widgets INCLUDE: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/;/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets;/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui;/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5//mkspecs/linux-g++-64
Core    LIBRARIES: Qt5::Core
Gui     LIBRARIES: Qt5::Gui
Widgets LIBRARIES: Qt5::Widgets
Core    DEFINITIONS: -DQT_CORE_LIB
Gui     DEFINITIONS: -DQT_GUI_LIB;-DQT_CORE_LIB
Widgets DEFINITIONS: -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB;-DQT_GUI_LIB;-DQT_CORE_LIB
Core    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS: QT_CORE_LIB
Gui     COMPILE_DEFINITIONS: QT_GUI_LIB;QT_CORE_LIB
Widgets COMPILE_DEFINITIONS: QT_WIDGETS_LIB;QT_GUI_LIB;QT_CORE_LIB
Core    EXECUTABLE_COMPILE_FLAGS: -fPIE
Gui     EXECUTABLE_COMPILE_FLAGS: -fPIE
Widgets EXECUTABLE_COMPILE_FLAGS: -fPIE
Using GnuCXX compiler.

Building DEBUG build.

Sentinel GL -- C++ Project V 0.1.

(c) Markus-Hermann Koch, mhk@markuskoch.eu, 2015/04/28-?

Primary directory is /home/kochmn/projects/sentinel/build
System is Linux
Generating configuration header: "/home/kochmn/projects/sentinel/build/../build/mhk_cmake_config.h"
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/kochmn/projects/sentinel/build

kochmn@Ulyss:~/projects/sentinel/build$ make 
Scanning dependencies of target optimization_automoc
[  5%] Automatic moc for target optimization
[  5%] Built target optimization_automoc
Scanning dependencies of target optimization
[ 11%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/optimization.dir/home/kochmn/projects/sentinel/src/optimization/linalg.cpp.o
[ 17%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/optimization.dir/optimization_automoc.cpp.o
Linking CXX static library liboptimization.a
[ 17%] Built target optimization
Scanning dependencies of target qt_automoc
[ 23%] Automatic moc for target qt
[ 23%] Built target qt_automoc
Scanning dependencies of target qt
[ 29%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/qt.dir/home/kochmn/projects/sentinel/src/qt/form_main.cpp.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/qt.dir/qt_automoc.cpp.o
Linking CXX static library libqt.a
[ 35%] Built target qt
Scanning dependencies of target sentinel_automoc
[ 41%] Automatic moc for target sentinel
[ 41%] Built target sentinel_automoc
[ 47%] Generating qrc_application.cpp
[ 52%] Generating ui_main.h
[ 58%] Generating moc_ui_main.cpp
/home/kochmn/projects/sentinel/build/ui_main.h:0: Note: No relevant classes found. No output generated.
[ 64%] Generating ui_dialog_setup_game.h
[ 70%] Generating moc_ui_dialog_setup_game.cpp
/home/kochmn/projects/sentinel/build/ui_dialog_setup_game.h:0: Note: No relevant classes found. No output generated.
Scanning dependencies of target sentinel
[ 76%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sentinel.dir/home/kochmn/projects/sentinel/src/sentinel.cpp.o
[ 82%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sentinel.dir/moc_ui_main.cpp.o
[ 88%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sentinel.dir/moc_ui_dialog_setup_game.cpp.o
[ 94%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sentinel.dir/qrc_application.cpp.o
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sentinel.dir/sentinel_automoc.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable sentinel
[100%] Built target sentinel
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CMake generation order is computed from dependencies between files and targets. If your *qt* library depends on headers generated from .ui files, then you have to add `${qt_UI_H}` in inputs of target `qt`:

```
QT5_WRAP_UI(qt_UI_H ${qt_UI})
[...]
add_library(qt "${DIR_SRC}/qt/form_main.cpp" ${qt_UI_H})
```

And CMake should normally execute UIC on .ui files before compiling `libqt`

By the way using `target_link_libraries` only set dependencies between targets **at link time**. At compile time, the normal behavior is "All source files should be found". In your case, some headers are generated, so setting these headers as input of a target ensures that the macro which generates them (QT5_WRAP_UI) will be executed before the compilation of the target.

Comment: This actually works! Adding ${qt_UI_H} did the trick. I am baffled that cmake is intelligent enough to determine that now UIC needs to be called first. But apparently it is! In any case: Thanks for your speedy help! :-)

Comment: CMake is a powerful tool. Sometimes capricious, but useful ;)